# Bash Functions | updating variables without echoing in terminal

Tags: bash

I have a function called freespace_function, I use this function to update the $free_disk_space variable as the script executes. The problem I am having is every time I call the function in my script it echos the value in terminal. I cannot remove the echo in the function, else it has zero output. I just want the function to silently execute (update the free_disk_space) without giving output in the terminal.

```
freespace_function () { 
    local function_result="$(df -m "${destination}" | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}')"
    echo "${function_result}"
    free_disk_space=$(freespace_function)
}

# inner loop
          while [[ "${free_disk_space}" -lt "${source_size}" ]] ; do
                echo "${free_disk_space} MB is not enough free space" 
                read -r -n 1 -p "please create free disk space to continue..." 
                freespace_function
                if [[ "${free_disk_space}" -gt "${source_size}" ]] ; then   
                    # breaks out of the inner loop when the if free space condition is true
                    break
                fi  
          done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think you need to redesign your function such that it does not use a variable assignment. Something like this

```
freespace_function () {
    # it's a better practice to explicitly pass parameters to functions instead of relying on globals
    local destination=$1
    echo "$(df -m ${destination} | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}')"
}

# re-evaluates but won't print 
# notice that the condition is evaluating on the result of a sub-shell instead of a variable
while [[ "$(freespace_function /tmp/dir)" -lt "${source_size}" ]] ; do
      echo "${free_disk_space} MB is not enough free space"
      read -r -n 1 -p "please create free disk space to continue..."

      # no need to explicitly break out of the loop
done
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, and yes, I noticed that my global variables weren't updating while the outer and inner loop traversed, so I call the functions instead.  Not sure how I going to do it with the source var, as it is in the loop, depends on the for a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `> /dev/null`. It redirects the output to `/dev/null`. `/dev/null` accepts all output and does nothing with it.

So your code whould be:

```
freespace_function () { 

    local function_result="$(df -m "${destination}" | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}')"

    echo "${function_result}"

    free_disk_space=$(freespace_function)
}


# inner loop

          while [[ "${free_disk_space}" -lt "${source_size}" ]] ; do


                echo "${free_disk_space} MB is not enough free space" 

                read -r -n 1 -p "please create free disk space to continue..." 

                freespace_function > /dev/null

                if [[ "${free_disk_space}" -gt "${source_size}" ]] ; then   

                    # breaks out of the inner loop when the if free space condition is true

                    break
                fi  
          done
```